# ContextListener at tomcat within eclipse triggering on every request

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I thought implementing the ContextListener and adding it to web.xml like this:
class:

```
public class StartupContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("ContextListener running...");
}
...
```

web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <display-name>StartupListener</display-name>
        <listener-class>com.ffleuchten.webtemplate.contextlisteners.StartupContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

should trigger the contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent) method once, when the first request is coming in.
I have eclipse running here with tomcat "inside" it. And the servletcontextlistener triggers on every request? Did I not understand the concept of Contextlisteners or is the eclipse-tomcat working in a different way? Interesting: I see this line in the default out, although I did not change any code or files right after a request and before my contextListener triggering:

```
Sep 27, 2023 2:32:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
Sep 27, 2023 2:32:56 PM ContextListener running...
```

So what's happening here? Any suggestions?

edit: I found the solution! eclipse was reloading the application, because I write a default configuration on request within the space, where eclipse is watching for changes (in this case I overwrite a file from the 'resource' directory) => it reloaded the application => the Servletcontextlistener triggered, as the application "started up" everytime this happens.

Comment: You should not change the subject to indicate it it solved. Post your solution as a answers and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! eclipse was reloading the application, because I write a default configuration on request within the space, where eclipse is watching for changes (in this case I overwrite a file from the 'resource' directory) => it reloaded the application => the Servletcontextlistener triggered, as the application "started up" everytime this happens.